# Do do i get the balance rank of a user efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL so i would like to ask this. I have an table with `my_id` (primary key) and `balance`. There are millions of rows of data in the table. I want to find what rank the `my_id` row of `4` stands. What I mean by ranking is, if the entire table was sorted by the balance amount (people with the most money would be rank 1 and the person with the lowest amount of money would be the last). How can  I get someone's rank efficiently.

```
my_id | balance
---------------
1     | 5
2     | 1
3     | 45
4     | 81
5     | 95
6     | 45
```

In this where `my_id = 4` would have the rank of `2` because he is the second richest. I understand maybe I might need to indexing as well?

Where `my_id = 6`, would have rank of `3`. And `my_id = 3` would also have the rank of `3` because they are duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select count(*) + 1
from t
where t.balance > (select t2.balance from t where t2.my_id = 4);
```

With indexes on `(my_id, balance)` and `(balance)`, this is likely to be the fastest approach:

```
create index idx_t_balance on t(balance);
```

The balance on `my_id` should be taken care of assuming that it is the primary key in the table.

A more canonical solution uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by balance desc) as rnk
      from t
     ) t
where my_id = 4;
```

Note:  Both of these use `rank()` because you specify "rank" in the question.  There is similar logic using `dense_rank()` or `row_number()` if that is the logic you want (these differ in how they handle duplicates).

Comment: I am very new to indexing, could you show me what command I would need to run to start indexing? Also would indexing effect my insert statements and my update statements?

Comment: When it comes to duplicates, I want them to have the same rank. Which would I use `dense_rank()` or `row_number()`

Comment: Also is the window functions more efficient than the first sql statement you gave me?

Comment: Also one more question, which part of the sql statement is actually giving me the number `2` (the rank of the user). Because all I see is `count(* + 1)` and `t.*` in the select statement

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov . . . With the right indexes, the correlated subquery should be the fastest solution for a single user.  In the first query, only the rank is returned.  In the second, the entire row is returned.